# Sugar ORM how do i add data to a row in the table

Tags: java, mysql, android-studio, sugarorm

Good day all i am using android studio, I have a fairly good idea of how to use sugar ORM at this point, but there's one thing that I just cant find or figure out.

So i have an activity named UserProfiles.java in which i ask the user for various things and then i store them in the database. So at this point i have about 20 records/rows in the database. The problem however is when i send the user to the next activity (UserPins.java) i ask them to set some additional information now how do i add this information to the same line as the data that has the User Profiles information?

```
//this is my UserProfiles.java

   package com.chika.mia;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import com.chika.mia.models.Mia;


    public class UserProfile extends AppCompatActivity implements            View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText Name, PhoneNumber, Email, Password, Address;
    private Button SaveUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_profile);
        Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name);
        PhoneNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.PhoneNumber);
        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Email);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);
        Address = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Address);
        SaveUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SaveUser);
        SaveUser.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Mia m = new Mia();
        m.setName(register.g);
        m.setPhoneNumber(Integer.parseInt(PhoneNumber.getText().toString())) ;
        m.setEmail(register.i) ;
        m.setPassword(register.h);
        m.setAddress(Address.getText().toString()) ;
        m.setLocation("MiaL");
        m.setWipePhone("MiaWP");
        m.setDispMessage("MiaDM");
        m.setAlarm("MIAA");
        m.setShutdown("MIASD");
        m.save();

        Toast.makeText(this, " " + m.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, UserPins.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

And this is my Userpins.java

```
package com.chika.mia;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.chika.mia.models.Mia;
import com.orm.query.Condition;
import com.orm.query.Select;

public class UserPins extends AppCompatActivity implements     View.OnClickListener {
private EditText     UserLocation,UserWipePhone,UserDisplayMsg,UserAlarm,UserShurdown;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_pins);
    UserLocation = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserLocation);
    UserWipePhone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserWipePhone);
    UserDisplayMsg = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserDisplayMsg);
    UserAlarm = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserAlarm);
    UserShurdown = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UserShutdown);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    Mia m = new Mia();
    Select.from(Mia.class).where(Condition.prop("Name").eq(register.i)).list();
    m.setLocation(UserLocation.getText().toString());
    m.setWipePhone(UserWipePhone.getText().toString());
    m.setDispMessage(UserDisplayMsg.getText().toString());
    m.setAlarm(UserAlarm.getText().toString());
    m.setShutdown(UserShurdown.getText().toString());
    m.update();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AppSettings.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
  }
```

What am aiming to do is something like this, So for which ever user logs in say "Tom", i already have the login and registration page sorted out. It will go through the database and look for the name "Tom" or email "tom@gmail.com" and then add the userpins information to the appropriate column in that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a new record in Sugar ORM, you get a unique ID back from the save(). On your first activity, get the ID, and pass it to the next activity:

```
long new_user_id = m.save();
...
Intent intent = new Intent(UserProfile.this, UserPins.class);
intent.putExtra("NEW_USER_ID", new_user);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you can grab it in the new activity with:

```
long new_user_id = getIntent().getLongExtra("NEW_USER_ID",0);
```

You may then use the ID to get the record to update:

```
Mia m = Mia.findById(Mia.class, new_user_id);
```